# How Can I decide what data type i must use in any programming language?

Tags: numbers, type-conversion

My English is not good so i apologize for it.

i experienced little about java and C++. But there is a problem. I only use integer for integer numbers and double for decimal numbers. There are many types like float, long int etc. Is there a specific way to decide what i must use?

Answer (score 0):

It purely depends on the size of the data and of course the type of it.  For example if you have a very large number that cannot fit within the size of a machine word (typically mapped to an int[eger] type) then you would choose `long`, and so forth.

For a small number I would go with `char` (since it occupies one byte in C/C++), or `short` if the number is greater than 255 but less than 65535, etc.

And all of these again depend on the programming language.

Be sure to check your programming language reference for the limits.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Different numerical data types are used for different value ranges.  What range applies to what data type depends on the language you are using and the operating system, where the program is compiled/run.

For example, `byte` data type uses 1 byte of storage and can store numbers from 0 to 255.  `word` data type usually uses 2 bytes of storage and can store numbers from 0 to 65,536.  Then you get `int` - here the number of bytes vary, but often it would be 4 bytes with values of -2^31 to 2^31-1 - and so on.  In C/C++ there also qualifiers `signed` and `unsigned`, which are not present in Java.

With `float`/`double`, not only the range of numbers, but also the precision (the number of decimal places that can be stored) will be one of the deciding factors.  With `double` you can store a lot more decimal places than with `single`.

On the whole, the decision will be based on what data you need to store in it, how much memory you're willing to allocate and what platform you're running on.  Check your language documentation for more details.  For example, [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) describes [primitive data types in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

You must check first for the type of data you want to store with the reference of data types provided in that programming language. Then very important you must check for the range of that data type...